# Computing the PDF f(z)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Q: X~exponential r.v with parameter 1 (amount of time that takes for abuse to arrive)

Y~ Uniform distributed on [0,2].(time to load)

.X and Y are independent.

.Compute the pdf of the time for the bus to arrive plus the time to load.

. Then we are trying to find Z(x,y)=x+y

. In my picture, I have attached the work I have so far but I am just confused because I feel like my bounds are wrong, any feedback would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: If $x \sim Exp(1)$, then why do you have $\lambda$ in your equations?.Also your density of $f_{y} (z−x)$ is incorrect, I think. It should be $f_{z}(z) = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot I\{(z - x) \in [0, 2]\} dx$.

Comment: I just have it as a reference although I understand its confusing. oh okay, I understand why its [0,2]  since that the bounds for y. Thank you